# How to handle scope when generating bytecode with a handwritten compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, scope, bytecode, stack-machine

I have written a small compiler for a simple stack machine. It can assemble and handle scope/functions through a number of virtual machine hacks only. That is I have it define scope and in scope variable definitions in the bytecode itself.

Can I get some pointers on how I should be handling scope.

The problems I face are mainly, how do I let it know when to and when not to overwrite a variable outside with a variable inside, and similar. The bytecode is mutable and I would prefer to change it.

Other problems include how to retain variables outside after returning. So that a variable still has its value. I can push it to stack, but I could have a lot of variables.

I think there is some compiler work done to check these things, but I can't think of what would need to be done to do it.

Comment: Are you talking about closures?

Comment: Sorta, but no. Basically how to generate bytecode to handle variables with scope, or rather examples there of (which might be more helpful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to [rename variables at compile time to ensure there is no masking.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution#Alpha_renaming_to_make_name_resolution_trivial) So:

```
{
   declare foo;
   foo = assignment;
   {
     declare foo;

     foo = another_assignment;
     another_use = foo;
   }
   use = foo;
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
{
   declare foo_0;
   foo_0 = assignment;
   {
     declare foo_1;

     foo_1 = another_assignment;
     another_use = foo_1;
   }
   use = foo_0;
}
```

While compiling, you maintain one 'rename-stack' per variable. And:

1. Whenever you see a declaration, you generate a new name and push it to the corresponding variable's rename-stack.
2. When you see an assignment/usage, you replace the name with whatever is on the top of the stack.
3. When you leave a scope, you pop it off the stack.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually very helpful. I didn't think of keeping a separate rename stack for each variable. I was trying to do it on a scope basis. this way is much more elegant. Thank you!

Comment: How would I go about handling recursive statements then? That's a question that has been bugging me a bit.

Comment: Masking due to scope can be handled in the way I explained, *at compile time*, i.e. by renaming to avoid masking. On the other hand, recursive calls (and even regular calls) should be handled *at run time*. i.e. in the call stack. Its really a different problem altogether. Except that there is a stack involved there too ;)